# Does .defaultProps work with stateless React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Code:

```
export default function RoundedLink({ url, text, className, target }) {
  return (
    <a
      className={`${buttonCorners} ncss-btn-medium border-black ncss-brand pt2-sm pr5-sm pb2-sm pl5-sm ${className}`}
      href={url}
      rel="noopener"
      target={target}
    >
      {text}
    </a>
  );
}

RoundedLink.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
  target: '_self',
};

RoundedLink.propTypes = {
  url: string.isRequired,
  text: string.isRequired,
  className: string,
  target: string,
};
```

But when I test it I get `undefined` in the className and target:

```
expect(RoundedLink({})).toMatchSnapshot();

...

 <a
    className="css-1by5joz ncss-btn-medium border-black ncss-brand pt2-sm pr5-sm pb2-sm pl5-sm undefined"
    href={undefined}
   rel="noopener"
   target={undefined}
  />
```

1. Shouldn't this be erroring when I try to create it without a required prop?
2. Why is the default prop not populating?

My only conclusion is that defaults and prop types don't work if you are not using a `class` or `createReactClass` to declare your components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use defaultProps also on stateless function components. Could it be you are getting this behavior because you are calling the component just like a normal function instead of using renderer.create to instantiate the component:

```
  const tree = renderer.create(<RoundedLink />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Complete sample:

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import React from 'react';
import RoundedLink from './RoundedLink';

describe('<RoundedLink />', () => {
  test('#render', () => { 
    const tree = TestRenderer.create(<RoundedLink />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: `react-test-renderer` package?

Comment: yes you would need the `react-test-renderer` package.

Comment: Nice, that did the trick. I added a code sample. Bonus: it's actually emitting warnings about the missing props.